# WordPress doesn't respect the template hierarchy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, template-hierarchy

My theme has a custom taxonomy template ("**taxonomy-authors.php**") but WordPress *only* serves this template file when a term associated with this taxonomy is called. e.g. example.com/cpt/authors/john-doe

When loading example.com/cpt/authors/ it will return a 404. What I want it to do is to list all terms associated with the taxonomy "authors" when example.com/cpt/authors/ is requested.

Here's part of my **taxonomy-authors.php** file:

```
<?php
    if (have_posts()) :
?>
        <h2>List of Authors</h2>

<?php
        $terms = get_terms('authors');

        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo $term->name;
        }

    endif;
?>
```

Any pointers on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a taxonomy archive. There is a taxonomy term archive, but no taxonomy archive.

E.g. this URL makes no sense in the current system:

```
example.com/category/
```

But this does:

```
example.com/category/uncategorised/
```

Comment: Ah. I see. There's no way example.com/category can be utilised at all?

Comment: Yes, you can put a page  with a page template there, but there's no such thing as a 'term archive' out of the box unless you code one yourself.